# Using gmail address to send out emails with Postal

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, gmail, postal

I'm trying to send out an email from my Gmail account using [Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/):

```
dynamic email = new Email("Appointment");
email.To = "sergiotapia@outlook.com";
email.Send();
```

And I get this error:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: {"The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the 
>   client was not authenticated.The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.

Any ideas what I need to do to send this email out?

Here's my web.config setting:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="asdf@adsf.ly.com">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" defaultCredentials="false" userName="asdf@adsf.ly" password="asdf" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: I'm hoping the u/p information you entered is fake. If not, you should change your password, now.

Comment: Change `dynamic` to `var` - you will get compile-time checks for your code.

Comment: @JakubKonecki I believe the `dynamic` thing is because of Postal; that's what it returns.

Comment: @JakubKonecki: No; `Email` is a `DynamicObject`. https://github.com/andrewdavey/postal/blob/master/src/Postal/Email.cs

Comment: Thought `Email` is a regular class...

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Late nights and stale coffee strikes again. Thanks for the heads up. Hopefully a mod can remove that part from the question history.

Comment: @Serg Even if they do (you can flag it for removal from the edit history), you would be surprised how quickly Google indexes/caches Stack Overflow pages; you definitely need to change the info *now*. :) Go ahead... I'll wait... OK, great!

Comment: @JakubKonecki Nope; `Email` is a `Postal` class. The built-in .NET email class is `MailMessage`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the error clearly states, Gmail only accepts SSL connections.

Add `enableSsl="true"` to your config.

Comment: Clarification: I needed to add it to the `<network>` tag. See: `<network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" defaultCredentials="false" userName="asdf@adsf.ly" password="hunter2" enableSsl="true" />` - Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You should use secure connection when you try to sending an mail. Try this in your config;

```
enableSsl="true"
```

[`Problems sending mail`](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78775)

Comment: Nitpick: He's _sending_ mail, not retrieving.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. but now fixed by using this config

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="dotnet1235@gmail.com">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587"
                 defaultCredentials="false"
                 userName="dotnet1235@gmail.com"
                 password="bla_bla"
                 enableSsl="true"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

I follow the step on this blog http://fat-night.blogspot.com/2014/09/c-postal-mvc-5-menggunakan-gmail-mail.html